# how to find rows that contains several values from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

```
PRODUCTS
| id | name   |
| -- | ------ |
| 1  | pen    |
| 2  | pencil |
```

PRICES

```
| price | status        | product_id |
| ----- | --------      | ---------- |
| 1.0   | accepted      | 1          |
| 2.0   | closed        | 1          |
| 2.0   | not relevant  | 2          |
| 2.0   | closed        | 2          |
```

I found a way with subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE id in (select product_id FROM PRICES WHERE status = 'accepted')
AND id in (select product_id FROM PRICES WHERE status = 'closed')
```

But I think, it is not best way. What other ways are there? Is it possible to do it with JOIN or something else with no subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

I like using a join aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM PRODUCTS p
INNER JOIN PRICES pp
    ON pp.product_id = p.id
WHERE pp.status IN ('accepted', 'closed')
GROUP BY p.id       -- see note below
HAVING MIN(pp.status) <> MAX(pp.status);
```

### Demo

Note that if `PRODUCTS.id` is *not* the primary/unique key of that table, then you should use `GROUP BY p.id, p.name`.  Otherwise, `GROUP BY p.id` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method might be:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM PRICES pr
              WHERE pr.product_id = p.id AND pr.status = 'accepted'
             ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM PRICES pr
              WHERE pr.product_id = p.id AND pr.status = 'closed'
             );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `PRICES(product_id, status)`.

Note:  The performance gain comes from avoiding the aggregation.  However, Postgres has some nifty algorithms when the aggregation is (only) by a primary key.  So, it would be interesting to compare this solution to Tim's solution.